# flask sqlalchemy query the first three digits

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a sqlalchemy problem

`result = db.session.query(A, B).filter(A.device_id==B.device_id).all()`

What I want is the below query( it's wrong method) ：

`result = db.session.query(A, B).filter(A.device_id[:3]==B.device_id[:3]).all()`

What's the right method? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll have a go at this.

`session.query(A).filter(func.left(A.device_id, 3) == func.left(B.device_id, 3)).all()`

Sorry for the poor formatting. Hard to type on an iPhone.

About `func` see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html